# limit the number of tags in tdo mini forms

Tags: wordpress

I am using "tdo mini forms", i want to limit the number of tags that user can enter. I want that the user can not enter the tags more then 4.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: can anyone answer my question please.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your theme's functions.php file

```
add_filter('term_links-post_tag','limit_to_five_tags');
    function limit_to_five_tags($terms) {
    return array_slice($terms,0,5,true);
}
```